# No link to user's profile when a URL in a comment

Tags: support, comments, user-interface, hyperlinks

I noticed a comment from Jared to this [particular question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/49774/21516). The comment had a link to a URL but no link to user's profile. I think this must be a bug because not knowing a way to disabling profile links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because he don't have profile in programmers.SE site yet.

[He](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451969/jared-farrish) commented on Stack Overflow before that's migrated to programmers site.

[image]